# What study design should be used for a prevalence study and risk factor association

Tags: experiment-design, methodology, medicine

I want to estimate the prevalence of Hypertension in Diabetic patients and to check whether the prevalence is different in smoking and non-smoking people. Can someone help how to design this study ? is this a cross-sectional study or a cohort study? please answer to non-stat person.

Comment: Needs more information. What is objective? What can you afford?

Comment: Objective is to find the prevalence of hypertension in diabetic patients and to find out whether smoking increases the risk of developing hypertension. My data is of diabetic patients .

Comment: Since both these events take years to take effect if at all, this will be a long research design. Ideally you would want a cohort study but these are expensive and time consuming so you may try a cross-sectional design. In the end it boils down to how much effort you are willing to put into this and what your budget is.